# Can't simplify this summation

Tags: summation

Here's the question:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{i^2 + i}$

How do you express this summation in terms of n?

I'm at a loss of where to go with this. I know the formulas for the summation of $i^2$ and $i$, but I'm not sure where to use these (or if it's even relevant) because the only thing I can think of is to sum the denominators and then take their reciprocal, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac 1 {i^{2}+i}=\frac  1 i -\frac  1 {i+1}$.

[The answer is $1-\frac  1{n+1}$].

Comment: ...Did not think of that at all - thanks a lot!